# SQL select where 1 value is greater then and chose one from the other 4

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check my database with the following condition:

```
$map = getData($conn, "SELECT * FROM  map WHERE amt_cities > 4 AND neighbor_n = false OR  neighbor_w = false OR  neighbor_s = false OR  neighbor_e = false");
```

So the query must only return something if there are more then 4 cities. and if at least one neighbor is false.

So if there is an entry in my database with the following values:

```
amt_cities = NULL
neighbor_n = false
neighbor_s = false
neighbor_w = false
neighbor_e = false
```

nothing must be returned.

but when i run my query now with the example given above it does return this entry... Any help is appreciated.

(i know the title is a bit confusing so if you know a better one pls don't hesitate to edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just need parentheses:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM map m
WHERE amt_cities > 4 AND
      (neighbor_n = false OR  neighbor_w = false OR  neighbor_s = false OR  neighbor_e = false);
```

You can actually use `IN` for this:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM map m
WHERE amt_cities > 4 AND
      false in (neighbor_n, neighbor_w, neighbor_s, neighbor_e);
```

Or boolean logic:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM map m
WHERE amt_cities > 4 AND
      not (neighbor_n AND neighbor_w AND neighbor_s AND neighbor_e);
```

Note:  This might not be exactly the same if the neighbors could be `NULL`.

Comment: works like a champ! thanks for giving the options aswel :)

Comment: I suggest `((NOT ISNULL(amt_cities)) AND (amt_cites > 4)) ...` or design table again with `NOT NULL`

Comment: @Pரதீப் . . .No.  SQL Server does not have a boolean type.